# Given a line segment $PQ$ and a straight line $L$ not intersecting....

Tags: geometric-transformation, transformational-geometry

Given a line segment $PQ$ and a straight line $L$ not intersecting the line segment. At what point on $L$ will $PQ$ subtend the greatest angle.

I am looking for a geometric result..

Thanks.

Comment: Page 188 of https://books.google.com.au/books?id=UfdossHPlkgC&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=Given+a+line+segment+PQ+and+a+straight+line+L+not+intersecting+the+line+segment.+At+what+point+on+L+will+PQ+subtend+the+greatest+angle.&source=bl&ots=Wsw74_Xzj3&sig=ACfU3U0fo8NNgcSm6V6bFzBlOKbJzUAzng&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr4ai32qbqAhWx4jgGHYoBAisQ6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Given%20a%20line%20segment%20PQ%20and%20a%20straight%20line%20L%20not%20intersecting%20the%20line%20segment.%20At%20what%20point%20on%20L%20will%20PQ%20subtend%20the%20greatest%20angle.&f=false may be helpful.

Comment: But that doesn't provides a geometrical proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Draw a family of circles through the points $P$ and $Q$ (the centers of the circles lie on perpendicular bisector of $PQ$). Among these circles there are two which are tangent to the line $L$. If the line $L$ is not perpendicular to $PQ$ one of these two circles has a smaller radius. The point of tangency of the circle and the line is the point you are looking for.

The probably simplest geometric construction of the point in question is the following (see picture):
[image]

Let $O$ be the intersection point of $PQ$ and $L$. Let $L'$ be the line through $O$ which is perpendicular to $L$. Construct points $P',Q'$ on $L'$ such that $OQ'=OQ$, $OP'=OP$, $O\in P'Q'$. Draw a circle with diameter $P'Q'$. It intersects the line $L$ in two points $X$ and $X'$. The point with acute angle $XOP$ is the point which maximizes the angle. The other point $X'$ (not shown) maximizes the angle in the other half-plane with respect to the line $PQ$.

Comment: Can u tell me that how did u figured out that point of tangency of the circle and the line is the point we are looking for.

Comment: There are two cases: the point of tangency lies either a) in the same half-plane as the circle center or b) in the opposite half-plane. Let $R_T$ be the tangent circle radius. The circle intersects the line $L$ if $R\ge R_T$ in the case a) and if $R\le R_T$ in the case b). Consider a circle intersecting the line $L$. By inscribed angle theorem the segment $PQ$ subtends the half of the central angle for any arc point (here the points of intersection with $L$), and  the central angle is decreasing or increasing function of the circle radius in the cases a) and b), respectively.

Comment: In both cases the largest angle corresponds to the point of tangency. Larger angles are impossible because a circle with smaller (larger) radius does not intersect the line.

Comment: A last one!!, can u prove that there are exactly two circles passing through $P$ and $Q$ which are tangent to the given line.

Comment: The given construction is essentially the required proof because the constructed circle intersects the line  in exactly two points.

Comment: Thanks!! It really helped me a lot